# AlievePdf create dashed line

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf-generation

I need to create a schema to pdf. This schema contains a lot of dashed lines. If I paint it like not dashed lines:
[image]

But if I try to paint it by using dashed lines will paints next:
[image]

Don't paint constant bar length and constant distance between bars. String example:

```
    pdfItem.lineStyle(new RGBColor(color), 0.5, 1, 1,null, null, new DashedLine ([ 6 ]) );
    pdfItem.moveTo(firstPoint.x, pointsOnY-firstPoint.y);
    pdfItem.lineTo(secondPoint.x, pointsOnY-secondPoint.y);
    pdfItem.end();
```

I think this is why lines in the schema composed of several shorter lines фтв and it affects the display if line is dashed.
How can I fix this trouble?

Comment: I don't understand why somebody make -1 from this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to paint a dotted-line rule, you should paint it in one operation from the start point to the end point of the line ray. Otherwise you can have various problems occur:

- If you are attempting to concatenate segments together to form one longer dotted-line rule (*i.e.* without overlapping segments) each segment must end on a full increment of the first dot pattern, so that when the next generated dotted line begins after it, the eye will not see an error in spacing, or a dash that is too long.
- Similarly, if your line segments do overlap for some reason, the start point of the new segment must align with the start point of a dash on the underlying segment, or again you will have dotted lines that are either of different gap spacing or, in a worst-case scenario, completely solid in appearance.